# WooCommerce cart timeout/expire time

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron

German shops are covered by data protection.
How to set a WooCOmmerce Cart Timeout to 30 minutes?

Timeout have to clean cart (products and customer data like adress, email...).

I found this code, but what i have to change to reduce the cart timeout to 30 mins?

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WoocommerceLicenseAPI' ) ) {
add_filter('wc_session_expiring' , array('WoocommerceLicenseAPI',       'filter_ExtendSessionExpiring') );

add_filter('wc_session_expiration' , array('WoocommerceLicenseAPI', 'filter_ExtendSessionExpired') );
{

static function filter_ExtendSessionExpiring($seconds) {
    return (60 * 60 * 24 * 8) - (60 * 60);
}
static function filter_ExtendSessionExpired($seconds) {
    return 60 * 60 * 24 * 8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change time to 30 minutes try change this:

```
static function filter_ExtendSessionExpired($seconds) {
  return 60 * 30 * 24 * 8;
}
```

Comment: when i add the new code if ( ! class_exists( 'WoocommerceLicenseAPI' ) ) {
add_filter('wc_session_expiring' , array('WoocommerceLicenseAPI',       'filter_ExtendSessionExpiring') );

add_filter('wc_session_expiration' , array('WoocommerceLicenseAPI', 'filter_ExtendSessionExpired') );
{

static function filter_ExtendSessionExpiring($seconds) {
    return (60 * 60 * 24 * 8) - (60 * 60);
}
static function filter_ExtendSessionExpired($seconds) {
  return 60 * 30 * 24 * 8;
}

to my functions.php in child folder i get blank frontend in browser.